# Efficient way to keep clone of table row

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a PHP application which use MySQL database. It has table called profile which store user's details. Now there is a need of keeping snapshot of that profile when he perform a task. Which means whole table row related to a user must be cloned.

I found two ways of doing that.

1) Add another column to table to mention whether it was cloned. Then his original profile can be separated. (original/cloned). Profile data will be maintained in one table.

Other method is ..

2) Add another table similar to profile (with same fields) and store cloned profiles in that. Profile data will be maintained in two tables.

What is most efficient in terms of performance and usability ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have it in one table with just a `column/field` to distinguish whether it's a clone or original then you will have always double the number of records to handle. Whereas if it is on another table you have only one table to worry about each time unless you need both at one time. Another thing is if you have a separate table you have a **virtual back-up** for your main table. So, in any case that one is in trouble you have something to fall back on and vice versa. Additionally you don't put yourself in danger of mixing up the records if it is a separate table. In other words I would prefer your *second approach* rather than the first one.